# Let SQL wait until previous statement is done

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions

I have been searching around but I cannot find the correct answer, probably I search wrong because I don't know what to look for :)

Anyway, I have a TSQL with a `begin` and `commit transaction`. In the transaction I add some columns and also rename some columns.
Just after the renames and added column statement i also run some update statements to load data into the newly created columns.

Now the problem is that for some reason the update gives an error that it cannot update the given column as it does not exist (YET???).

My idea is that the statement is still working out the rename and the adding of the columns but already goes ahead with the update statements. The table is very big and has a few million records so I can imagine it takes some time to add and rename the columns

If I run first the rename and add statements and than separate the update statements, it does work. So it has to do with some wait time.

Is it possible to make sql force to execute step by step and wait until the complete statement is done before going to the next?

Comment: I would not recommend it (or your approach to your problem) but if you build a block of dynamic SQL and execute it after the statement modifying your schema - the code will be evaluated against the modified schema

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you modify columns (e.g. add them), you have to finish the batch before you can continue with updating them. Insert the `GO` keyword between table structure changes and updates.

To illustrate that, the following code won't work:

```
create table sometable(col1 int)

go

alter table sometable add col2 varchar(10)

insert into sometable(col2) values ('a')
```

But inserting `go` will make the insert recognise the new column

```
create table sometable(col1 int)

go

alter table sometable add col2 varchar(10)

go

insert into sometable(col2) values ('a')
```

---

If you do it in the code, you may want to create separate transaction for the structure changes and data migration. You can still wrap them it in one transaction for data integrity.

Comment: If u use the GO statment my variables are lost, i also do some other stuff in the transactions. Also the GO statement only works in "GO is not a T-SQL command. Is a batch delimiter. The client tool (SSM, sqlcmd, osql etc) uses it to effectively cut the file at each GO and send to the server the individual batches. So obviously you cannot use GO inside IF, nor can you expect variables to span scope across batches."

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't have anything to do with wait time. The queries are run in order. It's because all the queries are submitted all at once and therefore when it tries to validate your update, the column doesn't exist at that point in time. To get around it, you need to send the update in a separate batch. The following keyword needs to be added between your alter and update statement

```
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using select for update,

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#i2130052

This will ensure that your query will wait for lock, bit it is recommended to Specify WAIT to instruct the database to wait integer seconds so that it will not wait for indefinate time.